# Using Wine and playonlinux

Tags: wine, playonlinux

I cant seem to install anything that is Windows based using wine or Playonlinux. Everything always crashes, Pokerstars, Blackchip poker, Command and conquer, Marvel heroes...

Why won't anything I try and install ever work, what am I doing wrong ?
I am on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: How are you trying to install them? The best way is to run (NOT as root) `wine /path/to/exe`.

Answer (score 0):

you could run it from the terminal, and enter this in the terminal:

```
wine /path/to/file/exe
```

and it might work fine this way.